# C# Create an instance of a class in dynamic code not working

Tags: c#

I have a Textbox where the user can input some code and execute it. It creats a dynamic class and run it. In this class I try to create an instance of another class but the compiler doesn't find it:

Function to execute code:

```
private void Execute(string code)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    //-----------------
    // Create the class as usual
    sb.AppendLine("using System;");
    sb.AppendLine("using System.Windows.Forms;");
    sb.AppendLine("using System.Collections.Generic;");
    sb.AppendLine("using System.Linq;");
    sb.AppendLine("using System.Text;");
    sb.AppendLine("using System.Threading.Tasks;");
    sb.AppendLine();
    sb.AppendLine("namespace Testumgebung");
    sb.AppendLine("{");

    sb.AppendLine("      public class UserCodeClass");
    sb.AppendLine("      {");

    sb.AppendLine("            EA_Netzteil NG1 = new EA_Netzteil();");
    sb.AppendLine("            public bool KS1isUsed { get; set; }");
    // Function
    sb.AppendLine("            public string myFunction(int input)");
    sb.AppendLine("            {");
    sb.AppendLine("                 if(KS1isUsed)");
    sb.AppendLine("                 {");

    sb.AppendLine("                 }");
    sb.AppendLine(code);
    sb.AppendLine("            }");
    sb.AppendLine("      }");
    sb.AppendLine("}");


    //-----------------
    // The finished code
    String classCode = sb.ToString();

    //-----------------
    // Dont need any extra assemblies
    Object[] requiredAssemblies = new Object[] { };

    dynamic classRef;
    try
    {
        TextBox_skripte_runlog.Clear();

        //------------
        // Pass the class code, the namespace of the class and the list of extra assemblies needed
        classRef = CodeHelper.HelperFunction(classCode, "Testumgebung.UserCodeClass", requiredAssemblies);

        //-------------------
        // If the compilation process returned an error, then show to the user all errors
        if (classRef is CompilerErrorCollection)
        {
            StringBuilder sberror = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (CompilerError error in (CompilerErrorCollection)classRef)
            {
                sberror.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}:{1} {2} {3}", error.Line, error.Column, error.ErrorNumber, error.ErrorText));
            }

            TextBox_skripte_runlog.Text = sberror.ToString();

            return;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // If something very bad happened then throw it
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        throw;
    }

    //-------------
    // Finally call the class 
    string targetValues = classRef.myFunction(3);

}
```

HelperClass:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;


namespace Testumgebung
{
    public class CodeHelper
    {
        public static object HelperFunction(String classCode, String mainClass, Object[] requiredAssemblies)
        {
            CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string>
              {
                 { "CompilerVersion", "v4.0" }
              });

            CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters
            {
                GenerateExecutable = false,       // Create a dll
                GenerateInMemory = true,          // Create it in memory
                WarningLevel = 3,                 // Default warning level
                CompilerOptions = "/optimize",    // Optimize code
                TreatWarningsAsErrors = false     // Better be false to avoid break in warnings
            };


            //----------------
            // Add basic referenced assemblies
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.dll");
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll");
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll");


            //----------------
            // Add all extra assemblies required
            foreach (var extraAsm in requiredAssemblies)
            {
                parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(extraAsm as string);
            }

            //--------------------
            // Try to compile the code received
            CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, classCode);

            //--------------------
            // If the compilation returned error, then return the CompilerErrorCollection class 
            // with the errors to the caller
            if (results.Errors.Count != 0)
            {
                return results.Errors;
            }

            //--------------------
            // Return the created class instance to caller
            return results.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance(mainClass); ;
        }
    }
}
```

EA_Netzteil Class:

```
namespace Testumgebung
{
    public class EA_Netzteil
    {
    }
}
```

The problem is that EA_Netzteil NG1 = new EA_Netzteil(); doesn't work. EA_Netzteil is not found. The error is the following:

> CS0246: The type or namespace name 'EA_Netzteil' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

In a real class `EA_Netzteil NG1 = new EA_Netzteil();` is working, but not in the dynamic class. How to get it working?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: This is just a guess, but maybe it has something to do with assembly namespaces not being able to be merged together?

Comment: I have overall same namespace "Testumgebung" . I tried Testumgebung.EA_Netzteil NG1 = new Testumgebung.EA_Netzteil(); but also not worked

Comment: I dont see the definition of `EA_Netzteil ` anywhere in the code that you are compiling from the StringBuilder

Comment: This is more a suggestion than an answer (hence comment) but have you tried using [TypeBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder(v=vs.110).aspx).  There's quite a few examples around and I was able to get something compiling satisfactorily fairly quickly.

Comment: @Menahem what do you mean? Can you make an example?

Comment: @Alex, sure, maybe you can add the definition of `EA_Netzteil` to the text that you put on the string builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Project, your root namespace is always included.
In your dynamically compiled class, you have to manually add ALL namespaces.

Comment: I added   sb.AppendLine("using Testumgebung;"); to my string code but same error. I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: just got it working. It is somehow logical. At runtime is only the dynamic class there and of course can't find another classes because they are not there. But they are in the MainProgram.exe that is generated. So the solution ist to ad a compiler reference to the MainProgram.exe and add  manually his namespace if different. Solution for me was to add parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Testumgebung.exe"); in codehelper class